# Get the final entry in a S4 object R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, r-s4

I know for a df, I can easily do:

```
df[-1,]
```

but this does not seem to work for S4 objects (I am working with granges objects in specific but that shouldnt matter).
Is there some sort of -1 equivalent?

Is the solution just:

```
S4[[2]][length(S4)]
```

Example:

```
gr <- GRanges(
seqnames = Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr1", "chr3"), c(1, 3, 2, 4)),
ranges = IRanges(101:110, end = 111:120, names = head(letters, 10)),
strand = Rle(strand(c("-", "+", "*", "+", "-")), c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2)),
score = 1:10,
GC = seq(1, 0, length=10))
```

where I want to select "slots" (?) b-j.

If it was a df I would do:

```
gr[2:-1,]
```

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example of a `GRanges` object, and explain what you are trying to extract from it.

Comment: S4 slots are implemented like attributes, so they cannot be indexed like elements of a list, and you should not rely on their order. You can extract slot values by name using `slot` or `@`, and you can obtain a list of valid slot names with `slotNames`. This is all documented in `?slot`.

Comment: I added an example. The `slot` stuff has been helpful as I am trying to learn about S4 objects but I have not yet found a way to help my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn how to operate on `GRanges` objects, you should consult the methods described in `?GRanges`. The output that you see when you print `gr` is generated by the `show` method:

```r
show(gr)
## GRanges object with 10 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
##     seqnames    ranges strand |     score        GC
##        <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer> <numeric>
##   a     chr1   101-111      - |         1  1.000000
##   b     chr2   102-112      + |         2  0.888889
##   c     chr2   103-113      + |         3  0.777778
##   d     chr2   104-114      * |         4  0.666667
##   e     chr1   105-115      * |         5  0.555556
##   f     chr1   106-116      + |         6  0.444444
##   g     chr3   107-117      + |         7  0.333333
##   h     chr3   108-118      + |         8  0.222222
##   i     chr3   109-119      - |         9  0.111111
##   j     chr3   110-120      - |        10  0.000000
```

The output gives the impression that `gr` is a data frame, but it isn't: what you see has been extracted from the slot values (attributes) of `gr` and displayed rectangularly for your convenience.

```r
names(gr)
## [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

slotNames(gr)
## [1] "seqnames"        "ranges"          "strand"          "seqinfo"        
## [5] "elementMetadata" "elementType"     "metadata"       

gr@seqnames
## factor-Rle of length 10 with 4 runs
##   Lengths:    1    3    2    4
##   Values : chr1 chr2 chr1 chr3
## Levels(3): chr1 chr2 chr3
```

There are a few methods for subsetting `gr`. Don't expect them to behave exactly like the corresponding methods for data frames. To obtain a second `GRanges` object describing all but the first sequence (in this case `a`), you can do `gr[-1L]` or `gr[-1L, ]`:

```r
gr[-1L]
## GRanges object with 9 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
##     seqnames    ranges strand |     score        GC
##        <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer> <numeric>
##   b     chr2   102-112      + |         2  0.888889
##   c     chr2   103-113      + |         3  0.777778
##   d     chr2   104-114      * |         4  0.666667
##   e     chr1   105-115      * |         5  0.555556
##   f     chr1   106-116      + |         6  0.444444
##   g     chr3   107-117      + |         7  0.333333
##   h     chr3   108-118      + |         8  0.222222
##   i     chr3   109-119      - |         9  0.111111
##   j     chr3   110-120      - |        10  0.000000
##   -------
##   seqinfo: 3 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths

identical(gr[-1L], gr[-1L, ])
## [1] TRUE
```

*If* the sequences have been assigned unique names, then you can also subset by name, e.g., with `gr[names(gr)[-1L]]`, or `gr[names(gr)[-1L], ]`.

Run-length encodings of the columns to the left of the vertical bar are stored in the so-named slots and extracted using the so-named methods:

```r
identical(gr@seqnames, seqnames(gr))
## [1] TRUE
```

The columns to the right of the vertical bar are referred to as "metadata". They are stored together in slot `elementMetadata`, which you should extract using method `mcols`:

```r
mcols(gr)
## DataFrame with 10 rows and 2 columns
##       score        GC
##   <integer> <numeric>
## a         1  1.000000
## b         2  0.888889
## c         3  0.777778
## d         4  0.666667
## e         5  0.555556
## f         6  0.444444
## g         7  0.333333
## h         8  0.222222
## i         9  0.111111
## j        10  0.000000
```

The metadata are stored in a `DataFrame` object. You will find that, with regard to subsetting, `DataFrame` is more faithful than `GRanges` to `data.frame` semantics. `?DataFrame` explains  differences.

```r
mcols(gr)$score
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Im sorry, I saw that the object said "S4 Dframe" and I thought that meant it was S4. I didnt know that S4 Dframe meant GRanges - a unique object type separate from S4

Comment: S4 is the type, `GRanges` is the class. Compare `typeof(gr)` and `class(gr)`. The type of an object describes how it is stored internally. The class of an object affects how it is handled by functions.

Comment: What is the reason you use `-1L` and not `-1`?
Ah, I have to go learn the difference between `typeof()` and `class()` Thanks much.

Comment: This was great. thanks so much. Learned/learning so much. the `gr[-1L]` or `gr[-1L, ]` exampels worked well. using `names()` did not work in my particular case, as each entry within a GRanges package does not require a name.

Comment: It doesn't really matter here, but `1L` is a one of type `integer`, while `1` is a one of type `double`. Compare `typeof(1L)` and `typeof(1)`. R is quite flexible most of the time about which you use to index a vector, but my habit is to use the integer type, since indices are integral and never fractional. You shouldn't worry _too_ much about the differences if you are just starting to learn R. You can browse `?NumericConstants` if you're interested.

Comment: Yes, I showed `names` just to distinguish it from `slotNames`. If the sequences are named (and here they are named `a`-`j` by default), then you can extract the names with `names`. I don't know how common it is for the sequences to be named in practice.